# what is the meaning of DTD and SGML in HTML?

Tags: html, dom

***what is the meaning of DTD and  SGML in HTML??*** 
and does there exist a relationship between them ???
can any one help me , thank you so much.

Comment: check this http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/HTMLandSGML.html

Comment: Check [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_type_definition) for all your questions.

Comment: and http://www.w3schools.com/dtd/

Comment: Please search before asking such questions about terms that are readily defined and discussed elsewhere.

Answer (score 4):

[SGML](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Generalized_Markup_Language) is a meta language that defines a generalized structure of how data can be stored in a well-defined syntax. YOu can think of it as the predecessor of XML in every way.
HTML is a language that follows the syntax and rules specified by SGML, so it's a SGML compatible language. The same way, XHTML does conform to the rules of XML.

DTD (short for [Doc type Definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_type_definition)) is a language that can be used to define SGML (or XML, but usually XSD is used here) languages. A DTD specifies, which elements and attributes are valid in which context in a language.

tl;dr: SGML specifies the SYNTAX of HTML (and how to parse it), the appropriate DTD (not DTD as a standard itself - that ones specifies how DTDs are built) tells you which CONTENT HTML is allowed to have.

[Edit]: Just for clarification: SGML isn't a language on it'S own. Its just a standard that other languages can incorporate to specify their syntax without having to do all the work again. Defining an SGML language is, basically, as easy as writing another DTD, while it's a lot of work to fully specify your completely unique syntax and parsing rules. (Same for XML again, of course).